# Debian Bullseye Apache 2 failing to upload files to /tmp

Tags: debian, apache2

Let me preface by saying I am very much out of my element with back end server management, so if my question is lacking details or poorly worded, please politely let me know what you need for better context.

We are running 3 web apps on our server. 2 are in php and 1 is in perl. They were originally running in a Debian Stretch Apache 2 environment, and I was tasked with the undertaking of bringing the apps all to Debian Bullseye with Apache 2.

All of our web apps were up and running beautifully with the exception of the file upload feature.

This is a direct quote from my boss when he tasked me with research:

`Got a weird issue that it can't find the files uploaded to /tmp. I know systemd does weird stuff with apache2 /tmp and points it to a separate private folder, but that was already the case in stretch. Something in bullseye seems to be breaking it more. It's not perl or php specific since both the app 1 and app 2 are affected. jobtracker gives a "cannot find file /tmp/xxxxx.csv" error. app 2 complains about insufficient disk space, but that's just a default error because it can't determine the filesize being uploaded.`

`I can clearly see the timestamp on the /tmp/systemd-..../tmp/ path is being updated when I upload something, so it's doing something, I just don't know where it's failing`

So the upgrade to Apache 2 on Bullseye seems to have completely borked all file uploads across all of our apps, regardless of their native base language.

As I said, I am out of my element here, and tasked with this research to learn more about the backend communication of our server.

No internet searches seem to yielding anything, but I'm admittedly probably not wording this question correctly.

Does the update make naming conventions on file directories more strict? Is Debian Bulleye and apache2 missing a new dependency package we didn't know about? is it some sort of config permission? I genuinely am not sure.

We are running the most recent stable bullseye apache2 package: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/apache2

Here is a snippet of our perl code that failing when trying to access a file: `open(my $fh, "<", "/tmp/$csvfile") or die "Can't open $csvfile: $!";`

Here is a snippet of our perl code where it's failing on upload now:

```
sub pdf_folder
{
  my $self = shift;
  my $folder = ROOT_PATH."/materialimages/proofs/$self->{'_clientabbr'}/$self->{'materialid'}/";
  make_path($folder) unless(-d $folder);

  return $folder;
}
```

And just to reiterate, this is both in our perl written apps and php apps after this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Bullseye was reading our CSV files as the wrong mimetype. It was interpreting the file as application/csv, despite obviously not being an application.

This may be an actual bug in Bullseye, because both my boss and I have scoured the internet with no lucky finding anyone else with this issue. I may even report to Bullseye's devs for further awareness.

The fix was manually adding in our own mimetypes that interpreted this file correctly.